# How to pass parameter a in the newElement.setAttribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code to generate the textbox dynamically by using the JavaScript. It's working fine. But my issue is all generated textboxes have the same name. Is there is possible to prefix the textbox count with the textbox' name so that it is easy to post the textbox values?

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script>//addElement('INPUT','targetTag',{'id':'my_input_tag', 'name':'my_input_tag', 'type':'text', 'value':'txt2','size':'5'}); return false;
          function addElement(tag_type, target, parameters) {
           // var parameters = "'id':'my_input_tag', 'name':'my_input_tag', 'type':'text', 'value':'txt2'";
            //alert(parameters);
            var newElement = document.createElement(tag_type);

            //Add parameters
            if (typeof parameters != 'undefined') {
              for (parameter_name in parameters) {
               // newElement.setAttribute(parameter_name, parameters[parameter_name]);
                   newElement.setAttribute("text","button","name:my_input_tag","value:my_input_tag");

              }
            }

            //Append element to target
            document.getElementById(target).appendChild(newElement);

            if(document.getElementById('txthidden').value == "") { 
            document.getElementById('txthidden').value = 1;
            } else {
            document.getElementById('txthidden').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txthidden').value) + parseInt(1);
            }
         }

          function Submit() {
          var txtval = document.getElementById('my_input_tag').value;
            alert(txtval);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form method="post">
        <div id="targetTag"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Check"/>
        </form>
        <input type="text" name="txthidden" id="txthidden" >

        <input type="button" onClick="addElement('INPUT','targetTag',{'id':'my_input_tag1', 'name':'my_input_tag', 'type':'text', 'value':'txt2','size':'5'}); return false;" value="Add Input Tag" />

        <input type="button" onClick="addElement('INPUT','targetTag'); return false;" value="Add Input Tag W/O Parameters" />
        <input type="button" onClick="return Submit();" value="Save" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function addElement(tag_type, target, parameters) {        
        var newElement = document.createElement(tag_type);        

        //Add parameters        
        if (typeof parameters != 'undefined') {        
          for (parameter_name in parameters) { 
               newElement[parameter_name] = parameters[parameter_name];
          } 
        }        

        //Append element to target        
        document.getElementById(target).appendChild(newElement);        

        if (document.getElementById('txthidden').value == "") {         
          document.getElementById('txthidden').value = 1;        
        } else {        
           document.getElementById('txthidden').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txthidden').value) + parseInt(1);        
        }        
     }
```

Change this line in your html to this

```
<input type="button" onClick="addElement('INPUT','targetTag',{'id':'my_input_tag' + document.getElementById('txthidden').value, 'name':'my_input_tag' + document.getElementById('txthidden').value, 'type':'text', 'value':'txt2','size':'5'}); return false;" value="Add Input Tag" />
```

Here is a litle [demo](http://jsbin.com/emiza4/2) http://jsbin.com/emiza4/2

Comment: He needs a counter appended after the name. You can use the value of `txthidden` for that.

Comment: yes, thank you for your replay .  i am passing the textbox name in the  button On click event .how to pass the textbox box value as parameter.

        <input type="button" onClick="addElement('INPUT','targetTag',{'id':'my_input_tag1', 'name':'my_input_tag', 'type':'text', 'value':'txt2','size':'5'}); return false;" value="Add Input Tag" />

Comment: @Meena ... if you notice I modified your 'for...loop'  This modification will take the associative array you pass in as a parameter and populate the corresponding values in your new element.  If you pass {id: "mynewID1"} the element that is created will have the and id = "mynewID1"  any valid property will populate in the new element such as; style, name, value...etc...

Comment: No it show error can you explain how to assign txthidden this value to the parameter

Comment: @Meena ... Look at the input tag I coded in my answer.... Basically i populate your associative array with id: 'my_input_tag' + document.getElementById('txthidden').value

Comment: Is it possible to insert the line break after every textBox

Comment: after appending the element append a br tag too: `document.getElementById(target).appendChild(document.createElement("br"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a much **clearer** solution. You can save the current number of input fields in a property of the function (instead of a hidden input field).

Also you can create two function as a separation of concerns and **modularity** `addElement` and `addInput`, such as `addInput` will be a special case for `addElement` but you have to **type less** if you want to call it:

```
// creates a child element to a given parent
function addElement(tag, target, params) {
    var el = document.createElement(tag);
    // Add parameters
    if (typeof params != 'undefined') {
        for (var parameter in params) {
          if (params.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) {
            el[parameter] = params[parameter];
          }
        }
    }

    // Append element to target
    document.getElementById(target).appendChild(el);
}

// creates an <input> child to a given target
function addInput(target, id, type, value, size) {
  var params = {
    id:    id + addInput.cnt,
    name:  id + addInput.cnt,
    type:  type || "text", 
    value: value,
    size:  size
  };
  addElement("input", target, params);
  addInput.cnt++;
}

addInput.cnt = 1;
```

**HTML**

```
onclick="addInput('targetTag', 'my_input_tag', 'text', 'txt2', '5');"
```